# How to define the variable used in ng-include directive

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use my `company_address.html` template in some places but depending on route,
it's built of a different variable.

The template:

```
Username: {{ user.company.name }}
Company: {{ user.company.company_name }}
```

Data is loaded from `$http` service.

On offers page, a user is defined by `offer.user`, but on my orders page,
its defined by `order.user`. I woule like to use the same template for that purpose.

I would also like to mention that there is a user defined in `$rootScope` as the application
requires authentication.

I've tried with:

`<any ng-include="'path/to/company_address.html'" onload="user=offer.user">` for offers page and similar with `onload="user=order.user"` but this does not work. I know that onload modifes the paranet scope, and not the scope created by ng-include directive.

Is it possible to include the same html snippet with some object defined in the ng-include ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the ng-hide attribute hack as proposed by @james-sharp use the [ng-init directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit). This allows you to initialise variables on scope. Example:

```
<div ng-init="test1 = (data | orderBy:'name')"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any code brought in by an ng-include should still inherit from the parent scope so you should just be able to do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<any ng-controller="FooCtrl">
    <!-- Whatever html you want here -->
    <any ng-include="path/to/company_address.html"></any>
</any>
```

**Controller**

```
FooCtrl = function($scope){
    $scope.user = $scope.offer.user // or $scope.order.user
}
```

You can then use the `user` variable in your company_address template. If you really want to define the user variable in the HTML then you can do a pretty hacky:

```
<any ng-include="'path/to/company_address.html'" ng-hide="user = offer.user">
```

(assuming user isn't null)